# Is there any way to write information into a Contact in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I know about three mechanisms:

- Save Tasks (e.g. SaveEmailAddressTask) which can be used to save specific info like a PhoneNumber or an EmailAddress into a contact selected by the user
- SaveContactTask which can be used to create a new contact
- the Contacts API (Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts), which can be used to search/enumerate through contacts.

What I'm missing is a way to write a piece of data (e.g. a Note) into a contact (e.g. a Contact that gets returned from the Contacts.SearchAsync() API).

Is this possible with Windows Phone 7.1?

Stepping back, what I'm trying to do is put up some UI that allows the user to pick a contact, and import all the information (phone numbers, email addresses, etc) into a record in my app.

The problem I'm trying to solve is to identify whether I have ever visited that contact before and imported its data - if so, I just want to refresh it (as opposed to creating a new, duplicate contact).

An alternative approach to writing data into the contact would be to save a unique ID associated with the contact I imported, but I don't see a property like that on Contact either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything like this in v7.1 of the SDK, so you may have to look into approaches for defining your own candidate key, and given the nature of the data, you'll probably have to define several heuristics to determine your confidence of a match, and cope with several moving targets (names, numbers and email addresses can all change, and none are distinct).

Comment: That's what I feared.  Yep - the inherent volatility of the information makes it difficult to construct a key.  This is a pretty big scenario hole in the Contacts API... by contrast, iOS and Android both have this support.

Comment: ...or privacy/security hole, depending on your point of view.

Comment: If that is indeed your point of view, the hole is already there with the availability of the contacts API, which already allows an app to grab all the contact info.  Likewise, it is quite possible for an app to create a brand new contact with no interaction with the user.  So privacy/security isn't a great rationale for not completing the scenario for which the Contacts API was created, and exposing either a stable key (in fact there appears to be an internal ID in the Contact class), and/or allowing writing new information into an existing contact.  All IMHO of course ;-)

Comment: How do you create a new contact with no user interaction? As far as I'm aware, the only way to create a contact that I'm aware of is via a [Save Contact Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394013%28v=vs.92%29) which requires user confirmation

Comment: Yes, you are correct - my mistake re: saving a contact without user confirmation.  But you can grab any and all contacts without user knowledge... given this is already possible, I don't see how the update scenario opens up an information disclosure vector.